# What is this tag (finitely-generated) supposed to mean?

Tags: discussion, tagging

[finitely-generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finitely-generated) is the last strange tag I've lately seen. I could also add [integral-domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-domain) which includes 90% of algebra questions. Is there a reason for the introduction of such general tags?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @ArthurFischer.

Comment: I think it's used for proving that things are finitely generated, or for results that explicitly come from being finitely generated.  I don't think it was intended to be used with everything that happens to be finitely generated.